# Android Accessibility Service doesn't restart after crash

Tags: android, service, crash, accessibility

If my Android Accessibility Service crashes, the service is not restarted by the system until the phone restarts.Is this known? Do I have a method of restarting it if the system dosen't?
How can I act in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to unregister your service before the app done crashing.
You can do it by catching all exceptions in application class, then destroy your service.